# Binding chart LegendItem checkbox to series visibility in WPF in C# codebehind

Tags: wpf, bar-chart, dynamic-programming, legend, datavisualization.toolkit

I have multiple column series chart getting generated in C#. I am further trying to get the legend for this chart with the checkboxes. Such that the chart displays the column series for only legend items that are checked.

I need to do this in C# code behind and not in HTML. 
I have the below existing code that creates the multiple dynamic column series -

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> item in list)
{
  foreach (System.Data.DataRow dRow in dtTable.Rows)
  {
      <formation of listSource>
  }

  ColumnSeries ser = new ColumnSeries { Title = item.Value, IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Key"), DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value") };
          ser.ItemsSource = null;
          ser.ItemsSource = listSource;
          ser.DataPointStyle = columnStyleBrown;
          mcChart.Series.Add(ser);
          i++;
      }
}
```

And I further want to add something to -

ser.LegendItemStyle =

So I need to know how to create a legend style with the check boxes in c#.

There can be 2 ways of achieving this-

1. Either by modifying the existing legend to contain check boxes also (preferred)
2. Or to create a new legend altogether

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to show progress. It depends on what you have on how the solution will work out. This question will likely be closed.

Comment: The question has been modified to contain the progress code. An early response would be greatly appreciated please!

Comment: Really busy yesterday. But I'm glad you worked it out. Good that you added progress. People want to know they're helping someone that's stuck, not just someone that's fishing for free labor. The point is to learn and grow and provide information that's useful to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to resolve this -

xaml code -

```
<Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
<Grid.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="CategoryLegendItem" TargetType="DVC:LegendItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DVC:LegendItem">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Owner.Visibility, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter1}}" Margin="0,0,3,0" />
                        <Rectangle Width="8" Height="8" Fill="{Binding Background}" Stroke="{Binding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="0,0,3,0" />
                        <DV:Title VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
<DVC:Chart Name="mcChart"  >
</DVC:Chart>
```

Relevant C# code for dynamic column series -

```
ColumnSeries ser = new ColumnSeries { Title = kvpNuclide.Value, IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Key"), DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value") };
                ser.ItemsSource = null;
                ser.ItemsSource = listRelease;
                ser.DataPointStyle = columnStyleAqua;
                ser.LegendItemStyle = (Style)LayoutRoot.Resources["CategoryLegendItem"];
                mcChart.Series.Add(ser);
```